# Downloading map tiles/image from website

Tags: imagery, mapping

There are two Norwegian websites that have satellite imagery I need, https://kart.finn.no/ or https://www.norgeskart.no .

Is it possible to save a certain area when zoomed out so the scale is 200m, but at the resolution when zoomed in so the scale reads 20m?

I've tried to see if the images are in temporary internet files but modern browsers make them difficult to find.

Answer (score 2):

Saving imagery from webmapping services like those you mentioned sounds more like a webscraping task: Open the desired website, then open the inspection tool of your browser (ctrl+shif+c or ctrl+shift+i for firefox) and check in the network tab for image-tile-urls like this:

https://maptiles.finncdn.no/tileService/1.0.3/norortho/9/265/145.png

Further investigation should reveal the syntax of the url by changing the three parameters. I assume it's something like .../norortho/{z}/{x}/{y}.png.

It then shouldn't take more than two for-loops of scripting to download (and merge) your desired imagery, which then can be georeferenced in a GIS of your choice.

DISCLAIMER: Due to the EU's OGD directive most European countries offer satellite imagery for free use, so i suggest to do some research in this direction. If you decide to go down the somewhat shady web-scraping way I strongly advice you to not use the obtained data for anything other than private usage!

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting closer, the url looks like - 

http://gatekeeper1.geonorge.no/BaatGatekeeper/gk/gk.nib_utm33_wmts_v2?&gkt=15D056D3401FBCF52B92F8223D137C8EE4AEFC8C404EF2E94EFC036587D8DE3E73EB102EF36BE6E40DF5E383F0884F5BFCACA52296E953D98D018F0853CD0DA1&layer=Nibcache_UTM33_EUREF89&style=default&tilematrixset=default028mm&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix=17&TileCol=70051&TileRow=34611

There should be a WMTS service link I can copy into Global Mapper but it doesn't work.  I don't know Python at all.  Am I stuck copy pasting tiles?

Comment: I successfully used the link from your comment in QGIS by modifying the last bit as said: &TileMatrix={z}&TileCol={x}&TileRow={y}. Paste the link in the new connection diolog box by rightclick on 'XYZ tiles' in the QGIS browser panel. Unfortunatly I am totally unfamiliar with Global Mapper but I'd be surprised if it doesn't offer a similar option.

Comment: Great, I can see it in QGIS Desktop.  When I try to export the map to image, I set the width and height to 4096px, draw the square on the canvas (which then changes the px in the selection screen), set the scale to 1:25000, press save...but it's taking a long time to do anything and I end up cancelling.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Doesn't Global Mapper offer the functionality of adding a WMTS or TMS?

Comment: It does, but the WMTS is protected data and the TMS (the geonorge link that works in QGIS) results in an error.  The Norgeskart site is meant to be open data but perhaps there's an authorisation problem with the TMS link we've created.  It works in QGIS, I just have to figure out the export map to image options.